# DTD Validation Error Elements for Mixed Content

Tags: xhtml, dtd

The html snippet looks like below:

```
<h1 id="Ch1_1b"><p><label>1.1. INTRODUCTION</label></p></h1>
```

where label tag is a must element and p tag is an optional as per my custom DTD.

My DTD snippet looks like below:

```
<!ELEMENT h1 ((#PCDATA|p)*, label)* >
```

However the validator throws an error:

```
Error  testd.dtd:13:16:FATAL:PARSER:ERR_ELEMCONTENT_NOT_STARTED: ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
Error  testd.dtd:13:16:FATAL:PARSER:ERR_ELEMCONTENT_NOT_FINISHED: ContentDecl : ',' '|' or ')' expected
Error  testd.dtd:13:16:FATAL:PARSER:ERR_GT_REQUIRED: expected '>'
Error  testd.dtd:13:16:FATAL:PARSER:ERR_EXT_SUBSET_NOT_FINISHED: Content error in the external subset
```

Can anyone suggest the DTD code for the same where I can have the mixed content with label tag as the mandatory element and p tag as an optional element?

Thanks in advance.